# How do I show the git branch with colours in Bash prompt?

Tags: command-line, bash, git

I am using [this guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20160220130957/https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2013/08/git-tip-show-your-branch-name-on-the-linux-prompt/) to show the branch name in gnome terminal (Ubuntu 15.10) when working in a git repository. Based on the above I now have the below in my ~/.bashrc file:

```
# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes
```

...

```
# Add git branch if its present to PS1
parse_git_branch() {
 git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
 PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[01;31m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
 PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w$(parse_git_branch)\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

As a result I now get:

[image]

so it *works*. But why has the coloring of my user@host been removed? And I would also expect that the branch name should be colored. Before it looked like this:

[image]

UPDATE:
I have now tried this guide instead:

https://coderwall.com/p/fasnya/add-git-branch-name-to-bash-prompt

adding this to .bashrc:

```
parse_git_branch() {
     git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
export PS1="\u@\h \[\033[32m\]\w\[\033[33m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

and that works:

[image]

Notice in .bashrc I also have this (default):

```
# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes
```

I have yet to find the reason why that snippet gives the correct result and the other version does not. Any input on this?

Here is the version of my .bashrc that has the old snippet enabled that does not work:

http://pastebin.com/M8kjEiH3

Comment: Was `force_color_prompt` uncommented before?

Comment: Yes I have tried with both uncommented and commented same result. The guide posted above says its should be commented out.

Comment: Can you post your complete `.bashrc`? IIRC the default `.bashrc` doesn't enable colour prompts, so you have to change it to show colours. It depends on what you changed.

Comment: Your new snippet has colour codes in them (the `\[\033[32m\]` and similar parts) without any checks. The old snippet checks if colour prompts are enabled before using them, and if they're not enabled, well.

Comment: As far as I can see the old snippet also has that when it evals to true. And I did try with 'force_color_prompt=yes' enabled/disabled. I made sure to restart gnome-terminal after each change.

Comment: That's why I asked you to show the rest of the `.bashrc`.

Comment: Have a look at line 64, which should tell you why uncommenting `force_color_prompt` didn't help.

Comment: I have added a link to a pastebin of the bashrc file containing the version of the old snippet that does not work.

Comment: @u123 The `.bashrc` you just posted confirms my theory, you're setting the prompt *after* `unset color_prompt force_color_prompt`. Remove line 64 and it'll work.

Comment: Thanks that works. I never touched this part of my .bashrc file. Assumed that the old snippet would work without having to modify other parts of the bashrc file. I will stick with the new snippet since it works with a default .bashrc file - no need for removing line 64.

Comment: You could also just comment it.

Comment: @u123 don't worry about the default `.bashrc` too much. If you mess up, you can always get the original from `/etc/skel/.bashrc`.

Comment: How can I add this only if the current directory is a git repo? I tried an if/else based on whether or not the contents of $git_parse_branch() were empty, but this didn't work

Comment: For anyone wondering about the [color codes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124409) and [other magic symbols](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Controlling-the-Prompt)...

Comment: Thank you! I love it when deploying.

Comment: I'd recommend using `git-prompt.sh` instead. Nevertheless, there's no need to use `git branch` and pipe to `sed`. Just use `git describe --contains --all HEAD`

Comment: The leaseweb.com URL at the start of this post is no longer valid - it now just redirects to the labs.leaseweb.com homepage and the content no longer appears to be hosted anywhere on their site. I'm going to see if I can find an archived version.

Answer (score 228, accepted):

This snippet:

```bsh
# Add git branch if its present to PS1

parse_git_branch() {
 git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
 PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[01;31m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
 PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w$(parse_git_branch)\$ '
fi
```

Is meant to *replace* the default prompt definition:

```bsh
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
```

Which ends with:

```
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

[The `.bashrc` you posted](http://pastebin.com/M8kjEiH3) shows you're adding it *after* the default prompt definition and `unset color_prompt force_color_prompt` (line #64).

Either *replace* the default prompt definition with the snippet or leave your `~/.bashrc` as it is and comment the default prompt definition along with `unset color_prompt force_color_prompt` on line #64:

---

So part of your .bashrc could look like

```
parse_git_branch() {
 git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
 PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[01;31m\] $(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
 PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w$(parse_git_branch)\$ '
fi
# THE SIX LINES BELOW are the default prompt and the unset (which were in the original .bashrc)
#if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
#    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
#else
#    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
#fi
#unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

[image: screensot]

Comment: Verified the above and you are correct. I will stick with new version of snippet since it works without having to modify the default parts of the bashrc file.

Comment: it fails to add color to the branch name.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Test it with a copy of the default `~/.bashrc` in `/etc/skel/.bashrc`, you might have something interfering in your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: un-comment force_color_prompt=yes (line # 48) if the colors are not visible.

Comment: Faster: `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD 2> /dev/null`

Comment: To color your branch according to its status, you can use the native [git-prompt script](http://digitalfortress.tech/tutorial/setting-up-git-prompt-step-by-step/) provided by git itself.

Comment: With this method, if you are using any python virtual environment, keep in mind that this won't display the virtual environment name in the terminal.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS & Terminator console and it works like a charm!

Comment: Created a video to show the use of the  git-prompt script created by git itself https://youtu.be/6DczjqG9HbA

Comment: do i need to comment line `unset color_prompt force_color_prompt` or not?

Answer (score 208):

#### Ubuntu: Show your branch name on your terminal

Add these lines in your ~/.bashrc file

```
# Show git branch name
force_color_prompt=yes
color_prompt=yes
parse_git_branch() {
 git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
 PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[01;31m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
 PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w$(parse_git_branch)\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

Reload the .bashrc file with this command:

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: This worked for me on 18.04!

Comment: Thanks. Using: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Comment: It worked also for me on elementaryOS 0.4 Loki. As simple as open my ~/.bashrc with the command `sudo nano ~/.bashrc`, copy your code at the end of the file, save it, exit and reload the ~/.bashrc with the code you pasted above.
Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: Works on Redhat 6.8!

Comment: This worked and kept the colors! (Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: Wokred on ubuntu 19.04

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Comment: Worked for me in Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: How could I change the color and/or length of the git branch name that shows?

Comment: Working in 18.04

Comment: Works well for me and also shows the conda environment, when it's not the default one or when I go from another env into the default one.

Comment: Works fine for Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL2. Thanks!

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.10 working correctly ;)

Comment: Worked perfectly on 20.04 LTS

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (WSL)

Comment: I am not an expert, but managed to simplify parse method: `git branch --show-current 2> /dev/null | sed -e 's/\(.*\)/ (\1)/'`. Does anyone see any issues with this?

Comment: Worked perfectly on Debian GNU/Linux 9.13

Comment: Its working perfectly on ubuntu20.04 LTS

Comment: @nilon To change the color of the branch name, replace `01;31m` in the square brackets before `$(parse_git_branch)` with `33m`, which is much more pleasent for the eyes, especially when using the shell with purple background. List of colors here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-shell-change-the-color-of-my-shell-prompt-under-linux-or-unix/

Comment: @Jakob Note that 01;33m is for yellow even though your link says it's brown

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 22.04 and doesn't change the default colors of the prompt.

Comment: Perfect for Ubuntu 22.10

Answer (score 23):

For now, I followed this
https://gist.github.com/eliotsykes/47516b877f5a4f7cd52f and working,
liking it so far, though I'm planning to customize it further.

> In Terminal
>
> ```
> mkdir ~/.bash
> ```
>
> Copy the raw `git-prompt.sh` file from git contrib in to the `~/.bash`
>   directory:
>   https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh
>
> Inside `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` (choose the file where you
>   normally put any bash customizations/setup), add the lines:
>
> ```
> source ~/.bash/git-prompt.sh # Show git branch name at command prompt
> export GIT_PS1_SHOWCOLORHINTS=true # Option for git-prompt.sh to show branch name in color
>
> # Terminal Prompt:
> # Include git branch, use PROMPT_COMMAND (not PS1) to get color output (see git-prompt.sh for more)
> export PROMPT_COMMAND='__git_ps1 "\w" "\n\\\$ "' # Git branch (relies on git-prompt.sh)
> ```
>
> As long as you're inside a git repo, your Bash prompt should now show
>   the current git branch in color signifying if its got uncommitted
>   changes.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it's clear, concise, and does the job, and it works on other platforms too.

Comment: The following at the end of `~/.bashrc` simply appends to the distribution's default color prompt `export PROMPT_COMMAND='__git_ps1 "'${PS1%???}'" "\n\\\$ "'`

Answer (score 12):

Quick hack:

1. Adding this to `~/.bashrc`:

```bsh
parse_git_branch() {
     git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}

export PS1="\u@\h \[\e[32m\]\w \[\e[91m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\e[00m\]$ "
```

2. Restart the terminal, or source `~/.bashrc`:

[image]

More detail: 
https://medium.com/@thucnc/how-to-show-current-git-branch-with-colors-in-bash-prompt-380d05a24745

Comment: I had this in my centOS & RHEL VMs and worked there, but for Ubuntu this didn't update on switching the current directory. Had to follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/946716/826548) for setting and unsetting values

Comment: This works but changes the default prompt colors.

Answer (score 7):

Append the lines below to `~/.bashrc`:

```
export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=true
export GIT_PS1_SHOWUNTRACKEDFILES=true

export PS1='\[\033[32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[34m\]\w\[\033[31m\]$(__git_ps1)\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

Comment: works on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Awesome, working!!!!

Comment: Other answers were great, but this was the simplest, fastest, and least cumbersome change to make on Ubuntu 22.

Answer (score 3):

Go to home folder

click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to show hidden files.

Open .`bashrc` file and at the end paste the next:

```
parse_git_branch() {
     git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
export PS1="\u@\h \[\033[32m\]\w\[\033[33m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

In case you have your terminal opened, close and open again. Enjoy!!

Comment: Hello, I tried it and it works only where I switch superuser, can you tell me how to enable always?

Answer (score 3):

I use [bash-git-prompt](https://github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt). It's configurable and easier than writing your own, which I imagine is what many readers are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Why bother with using `sed`? as in ...

> git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* (.*)/(\1)/'

Much easier to just use:

> git branch --show-current

It outputs the current branch and no extra characters!

Comment: Indeed, `git branch --show-current 2> /dev/null | sed -e 's/\(.*\)/ (\1)/'` works for me.

Comment: Please always try to provide the full answer even if you you are trying to improve someone else's answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Topic is old but I will post being able to help someone.
In the .bashrc file located inside the user's local folder, replace the existing PS1 with this one:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\[\033[1;36m\]$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")\[\033[01;34m\]$\[\033[00m\]'
```

If you want to change the color of the branch change the color before the parameter $ (__ git_ps1 "(% s)") that is, change this value:

```
 \[\033[1;36m\]
```

color chart
https://gist.github.com/avelino/3188137

Answer (score 2):

My variant for KUbuntu 20.04 LTS, derived from the original value of the `PS1`:

```
# put into ~/.bashrc
parse_git_branch() {
     git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
export PS1="\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[33m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I hadn't enabled the option

**Run command as a login shell** in

*Terminal* → *Edit* → *Profile Preferences* → *Command*

Comment: I think it's visually apparent from the question that this probably isn't the case here, but it may apply to others.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
parse_git_branch
```

with

```
parse_git_branch 2>/dev/null
```

in your PS1 definition and live happily ever after.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo vi .bashrc
```

---

### Write below code the button of the file:

```
git_branch() {
 git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}
export PS1="\[\033[1;36m\]\u\[\033[1;31m\]@\[\033[1;32m\]\h:\[\033[1;35m\]\w\[\033[1;31m\]\$\[\033[0m\]\$(git_branch)\$ "
```

```
source .bashrc
```

Comment: You should not need to use `sudo` to modify your own login file

Answer (score 0):

Best and short solution.
Modify .bashrc file located in **~/** directory.
Change PS1 variable. In my case it is 60 line.
Excerpts of .bashrc file with modified PS1 variable:

```bash
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[01;36m\]`__git_ps1`\[\033[00m\]\n\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
```

I've add **`__git_ps1`** variable and **\n** for new line for better
readability.
Worked in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and 20.04.4 LTS with git installed.
Example:
[sample of the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avaPG.png)

Answer (score -1):

In my case I didn't overwrite the `PS1` variable because I had to preserve the prepended environment that is added by anaconda package, that is the `(base)` in the image bellow. I use Ubuntu 20.04, and all I wanted is to append the branch at the end, thanks to @thucnguyen as my solution is based on his one:

[image: terminal screenshot]

```sh
parse_git_branch() {
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1) /'
}
export PS1="$PS1\[\e[91m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\e[00m\]"
```