# VS Code terminal in Ubuntu showing branch name

Tags: git

I am new to linux/Ubutu.

I downloaded the VS Code and i extensively use VS Code terminal in windows because that contain me into one window with out me needing to go to external shell or bash.

In VS code terminal, using git bash as terminal, in windows i used to be able to see which branch i am on. But in ubuntu, i am not able to.

Can anyone please help me how i can have something like this in VS Code terminal in ubuntu showing current branch name.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I show the git branch with colours in Bash prompt?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/730754/how-do-i-show-the-git-branch-with-colours-in-bash-prompt)

Comment: maybe but since i am new to ubuntu, i was thinking if there is easy solution like vs code extension